# R: ggplot box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame as follows:

```
   Calories Protein TotalFat
1       717    0.85    81.11
2       717    0.85    81.11
3       876    0.28    99.48
4       353   21.40    28.74
5       371   23.24    29.68
6       334   20.75    27.68
7       300   19.80    24.26
9       403   24.90    33.14
11      394   23.76    32.11
12       98   11.12     4.30
```

I would like to make a `boxplot` using `ggplot`. I can do this using base R using the following code

```
boxplot(df)
```

But how do I do with `ggplot`?

Comment: Maybe try some examples from the manual for `??geom_boxplot` first? http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html

Comment: This document does not have what I am looking for.

Comment: You have to reshape your data from wide to long format: `library(tidyverse);df %>% gather() %>% ggplot(aes(key, value)) + geom_boxplot()`.

Comment: @lukeA Thank you, it work.s Please post it as answer, so I can accept it. Not sure why the question was downvoted. A legitimate question.

Comment: Downvotes are maybe due to the question beeing a duplicate or seeing no try using ggplot. I don't know, never understood the the use of downvotes on SO. I'll post an answer...

Comment: Believe me, I tried but the examples in net are using factor variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `ggplot`, you should reshape your data from wide format to long format so that it looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather %>% head(20)
#         key  value
# 1  Calories 717.00
# 2  Calories 717.00
# ...
# 11  Protein   0.85
# 12  Protein   0.85
# ...
```

You can do

```
df %>% 
  gather %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key, value)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

... and get:

[image]

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T,text="   Calories Protein TotalFat
1       717    0.85    81.11
2       717    0.85    81.11
3       876    0.28    99.48
4       353   21.40    28.74
5       371   23.24    29.68
6       334   20.75    27.68
7       300   19.80    24.26
9       403   24.90    33.14
11      394   23.76    32.11
12       98   11.12     4.30")
```